# drop iptables chain forward

Tags: networking, iptables

I created the following rules (for FORWARD only):

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s ##MYIPHERE## -j ACCEPT
```

And then I run iptables -L and get this:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  ##MYREVERSEDNS##     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere
```

So I can see that the default policy is to drop, however why is the first line like this:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Does this mean the default policy is being overwritten and that all traffic from anywhere is allowed to be forwarded? Do I need to add another rule? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because `iptables -L` doesn’t include all details. It only gives a rough overview. To get a more detailed list, use the verbose switch: `iptables -vL`. It’ll look like this:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 363K packets, 256M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere
```

As you can see, the interface names (only `docker0` in this example) are visible.

If you want the “code” to recreate the rules exactly, use the `iptables-save` command:

```
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```